# Is it possible through JavaScript or PHP to save a variable permanently on the hosted server?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, local-storage, hosting

Basically, I have a form with checklist inputs. If one user selects one of the inputs and submits the form, I don't want other users to be able to see that option anymore.

My first thought is to store a variable on the server, one assigned to each input. If an input is checked when the form is submitted, its assigned variable changes. Then use an if else any time the page loads to check each variable and any that have changed, remain hidden.

Here's what I have so far using JavaScript, but as expected, the changes in JavaScript aren't permanent on the server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<style>
.hide {
    display:none;
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
</style>

<h3>Schedule this week's appointment!</h3>
<form action="form_test.html" onSubmit="reserveApt()">
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="monday"><label for="monday">Monday</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="tuesday"><label for="tuesday">Tuesday</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="wednesday"><label for="Wednesday">Wednesday</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="thursday"><label for="thursday">Thursday</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check5" name="friday"><label for="friday">Friday</label><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function reserveApt() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("check1");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("check2");
    var input3 = document.getElementById("check3");
    var input4 = document.getElementById("check4");
    var input5 = document.getElementById("check5");

    if(input1.checked == true) {
        input1.className = "hide";
        input1.disabled = true;
    }
    if(input2.checked == true) {
        input2.className = "hide";
        input2.disabled = true;
    }
    if(input3.checked == true) {
        input3.className = "hide";
        input3.disabled = true;
    }
    if(input4.checked == true) {
        input4.className = "hide";
        input4.disabled = true;
    }
    if(input5.checked == true) {
        input5.className = "hide";
        input5.disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes - you could store it in a flat file or a database.

Comment: as @JayBlanchard mentioned, you could persist the variable in a file, by caching it (if you have a caching system) or writing it to a file. Note that this might not be the approach you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to tackle the problem you are trying to solve with your approach, it would be very inefficient. Use persistent data instead. Use something like MySQL, MariaDB, or even MongoDB to keep track of which days are being taken already.

You could create a table that holds the exact mm-dd-yy (month-day-year) of the day that the apartment would be reserved. This will not only allow you to store permanently your reservations and query your existing ones, but also will allow you to tie actual dates, so you can have reservations on week days tied to an actual date, not just a day in general.

Here are some links to get started with MySQL with PHP (the most famous database for PHP).

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_mysql.htm

You will likely need to install MySQL on your local machine.

Try bundled binaries that provide a PHP-MySQL ecosystem.

Windows only (and MariaDB):
https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Windows and Mac:
https://www.mamp.info/en/

I hope this helps!

Cheers!